# Android - Vector images losing quality?

Tags: java, android, image, vector

I have images from my designer that are Vector images that should be able to scale to all sizes and look good or whatever(im a developer not a designer). My problem is when I add it to my app using Bitmap's, the image loses quality.

(The M has jagged lines)

[image]

Does android support Vector images? Is it because I am rendering them as a bitmap? What is it?

Comment: Yes you can use VectorDrawable but its for api 21 and above. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable.html

Comment: That looks like your image is scaled somehow. How do you put these images to the screen? Just paste some code maybe.

Comment: On my side moving to ConstraintLayout instead of using LinearLayout or FrameLayout removes the blurry quality on vector drawable.

Answer (score 5):

Vector image has no guaranty to be sharp after rasterizing. There are a lot of reasons that could cause quality losing. Main reason is in point coordinates in vector files for example you have vector image 100x100 pixels and you want to show it in 100x100 ImageView and come of points in vector image would have coordinates like 23,5; 67,5 it won't be sharp, but if you'll increase ImageView size to 200x200 the real coordinates would be 47; 135 so in this situation image would be sharp.

Also you could use [SVG Android](https://github.com/japgolly/svg-android) or [Android-SVG](https://bitbucket.org/paullebeau/androidsvg/downloads) for displaying SVG images in android.

Comment: Okay, and what does the resizing to 200x200 do exactly? Im just a bit confused about that part

Comment: Also are the vectors supposed to be SVG files? The vectors that I have a PNG. I dont know if this actually effects the image but Im thinking it may.

Comment: @KyleJensen When we resizing 100x100 vector image to 200x200 all positions of points in this image will be multiplied by to, in my example 23,5; 67,5 become 47; 135. About second question - yes, there are many vector image formats and SVG - is most popular. But PNG is not a vector format, its raster http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raster_graphics

Comment: So your saying that PNG files arent vectors in this case? Because I thought PNG could be vector

Comment: @KyleJensen yes you are right, PNG files cannot be vector